# How to prevent labels from being cut off in matplotlib .mplstyle

Tags: matplotlib

I've been trying for awhile but I haven't found any `rcparams` that stop my xlabel from getting cut off at the bottom when doing a `savefig()`. It works fine if I do `fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)` or `plt.tight_layout()` before `savefig()`, but I'd rather the default behavior result in a nice plot.

Maybe I have something wonky in my .mplstyle? But is mostly just copy paste from seaborn. I include it below for reference:

```
# default seaborn aesthetic
# darkgrid + deep palette + notebook context

axes.axisbelow: True
axes.edgecolor: black
axes.facecolor: 333333
axes.grid: True
axes.labelcolor: white
axes.labelsize: 18
axes.linewidth: 0
axes.prop_cycle: cycler('color', ['30bbff', 'ff6b51', 'ffc851', '7de524', 'dbdbdb', 'ff00f3'])
axes.titlesize: 24

figure.facecolor: black
figure.figsize: 8.0, 5.5
savefig.dpi: 80

font.family: sans-serif
font.sans-serif: Arial, Liberation Sans, DejaVu Sans, Bitstream Vera Sans, sans-serif
text.color: white

grid.color: black
grid.linestyle: -
grid.linewidth: 1

image.cmap: Greys

legend.fontsize: 14
legend.frameon: False
legend.numpoints: 1
legend.scatterpoints: 1

lines.linewidth: 2
lines.markeredgewidth: 0
lines.markersize: 7
lines.solid_capstyle: round

patch.facecolor: 4C72B0
patch.linewidth: .3

xtick.color: white
xtick.direction: out
xtick.labelsize: 16
xtick.major.pad: 7
xtick.major.size: 0
xtick.major.width: 1
xtick.minor.size: 0
xtick.minor.width: .5

ytick.color: white
ytick.direction: out
ytick.labelsize: 16
ytick.major.pad: 7
ytick.major.size: 0
ytick.major.width: 1
ytick.minor.size: 0
ytick.minor.width: .5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your labels are somewhat larger than usual, you indeed need to leave more space at the bottom.

Instead of the default `figure.subplot.bottom : 0.11` for the bottom you may use

```
figure.subplot.bottom : 0.15
```

This should work if `fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)` works for you. Otherwise increase the number further.

Comment: Yep, that did it! I didn't know the syntax allowed for a second `.` to access arguments that far down. Now I do! Thanks!!